# How exactly does ng-bind-html work

Tags: angularjs

In this code taken from Angular.org:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example16-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.14/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="ngBindHtmlExample">
    <div ng-controller="ngBindHtmlCtrl">
   <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It displays the text:

> I am an HTMLstring with links! and other stuff

I have no idea where this text comes from. I've searched the two javascript files and it's not there. If I change "myHTML" to some other text, nothing gets displayed. Can someone please explain what ng-bind-html is all about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the example from: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

It which case it is in the controller in the file script.js:

```
angular.module('ngBindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])

.controller('ngBindHtmlCtrl', ['$scope', function ngBindHtmlCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.myHTML =
     'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with <a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>';
}]);
```

The following line sets it:

```
$scope.myHTML =
         'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with <a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>';
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I noticed that I overlooked script.js. Where is this script stored?

Comment: You can get at it in chrome by hitting f12, clicking on the Sources tab, going to the examples/example-example16 folder and then script.js

Comment: So this is a built-in script in Google Chrome?

Comment: No, scripts can be automatically downloaded from a server and do not necessarily need to come with the html in a <script> tag

Comment: What isn't clear is that the script.js file contains the dependency injection of "ngSanitize" but this is not used. So how is the sanitization being done?